# xml.child is not a function?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, function

For some reason AS3 does not recognize the child function of the XML class as a function.

In the docs:

```
child(propertyName:Object):XMLList
```

Lists the children of an XML Object.

```
var xml:XML = new XML (
    <body>
        <bar value = "1"/>
        <foo value = "2"/>
    </body> );

var f:Function = xml.child as Function;
trace(XMLList(f("foo")).toXMLString());
```

This code gives the error: `Error #1006: value is not a function.`

Upon further inspection, `f` is found to be `null`.
So my question is, how do I assign the `child()` function of the `XML` Class to a variable of the type `Function`?

On a side note, the reason that this is necessary is because of its use in a utility function, `forEach(arr:Array, f:Function):Array`, which executes the function `f` on each item in the array and returns the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of how Flash Player implements XML class, but

```
trace(typeof(xml.child)); /*xml being in instance of XML class*/
```

outputs "xml".

For your problem though, you can create another function of your own, which takes XML object and returns xml.child(). You can then pass this function as parameter to forEach.

**update wrt comments:**

Cleanliness wise, I think this whole functionality can be exported to another unit (class) which has a member variable containing xml. Now, a member function of this class can access the member variable xml and also take 1 parameter as required by forEach.

Otherwise, as a shortcut you can have something like:

```
private function actualFunction(xml:XML, name:String):XML
{
    return xml.child(name);
}

private function closureAroundActual(xml:XML):Function
{
    return function(name:String):XML
    {
        actualFunction(xml, name);
    }
}
```

Then use it in forEach as

> forEach(arr, closureAroundActual(xml)){}

I've just typed the code here, so the syntax might be a bit off. But, I guess, you'd get the idea.

Comment: yeah, but such a function would have to take two parameters, one for the xml object, and another for the propertyName:String parameter. Since forEach() accepts functions with only one parameter, I need to pass in either the xml.child function or a function with the same header as xml.child

Comment: This is the general approach you should take. In my case, due to the apparatus, I was able to get by by nesting the function in another so that the xml instance was in scope and I could call xml.child() taking only one parameter. So the function did meet forEach()'s requirements